# Incorrect date value: '' for column 'birthday' at row 1

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I'm new to PHP and I'm trying to create a registration form and I'm getting the

> "Incorrect date value: '' for column 'birthday' at row 1

error. At first I thought it was the query but I fixed it and I still get the error, it's just a different column. I've searched everywhere, and still nothing, please help.

**my add.php code**

```
<?=
$first_name = ( !empty($_GET['f-name']) ) ? $_GET['f-name']: "";
$last_name = ( !empty($_GET['l-name']) ) ? $_GET['l-name']: "";
$email = ( !empty($_GET['email']) ) ? $_GET['email']: "";
$password = ( !empty($_GET['psw']) ) ? $_GET['psw']: "";
$birthday = ( !empty($_GET['age']) ) ? $_GET['age']: "";
$phone = ( !empty($_GET['phone']) ) ? $_GET['phone']: "";
$ministry = ( !empty($_GET['ministry']) ) ? $_GET['ministry']: "";



$query = "INSERT INTO `member` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `password`, `birthday`, `phone`, `ministry`) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', '$password', '$birthday', '$phone', '$ministry')";
$hostname = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'catacumba';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'mysql';

try{

$db = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $db_name);

if ($db->query($query) === TRUE) {
echo "Record Created";
} else {
echo "Error Creating record: " . $db->error;
}

//close the connection to DB
$db->close();


}catch(Exception $e)
{
$error_message = $e->getMessage();
echo "<p>Error message: $error_message </p>";
}

?>
```

my create_account.php form

```
<form class="modal-content" action="Add.php" method="post">
            <div class="container">
                <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">X</button>
                <h1>Create Account</h1>
                <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
                <hr>

                <div class="parent">
                    <div class="child">

                        <div class="parent2">
                            <div class="child2">
                                <label for="f-name"><b>First Name</b></label>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="f-name" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="child2">
                                <label for="l-name"><b>Last Name</b></label>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="l-name" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

                        <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="child">
                        <label for="phone"><b>Phone</b></label>
                        <input type="tel" placeholder="Phone" name="phone" required>

                        <label for="ministry"><b>Ministry</b></label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Ministry" name="ministry" required>

                        <label for="age"><b>Birthday</b></label>
                        <input type="date" placeholder="Birthday" name="age" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember" style="margin-bottom:15px"> Remember me
                </label>

                <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#" style="color:dodgerblue">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>

                <div class="clearfix" id="createbtn">
                    <button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: You're using `method="post"`, so you need to get the parameters from `$_POST`, not `$_GET`.

Comment: You should also use a prepared statement to protect against SQL injection.

Comment: `<?=` is for echoing, you should be using `<?php`

Comment: As mentioned, first and foremost, see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](https://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Incorrect value for column** is a MySQL error **related to the column datatype** you have chosen for `birthday`.

If the `birthday` value you are inserting is any different than the MySQL `date` data type `2021-02-22 17:03:24` you will get this column type error.

Make sure the birthday dates you are inserting are in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

As for using `mysqli`, don't. Use [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) instead.